# Subview below subview does not call gesture recognizer function

Tags: ios, objective-c, ipad, uiview, uitapgesturerecognizer

I have two `UIView` added to `ViewController` with `UITapGestureRecognizer`. Their frames are in collision (lets say they are equal for easier understanding), and when I click on `UIView` I want to trigger recognizer function for both views, not just one that is last added as subview. Is there any way to do that?

code for creating UIViews and gestures:

```
UIView *a = [[UIView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 50, 50)];
UITapGestureRecognizer *aa =
[[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(handleDeviceClick:)];
[a addGestureRecognizer:aa];
[self.view addSubview:a];
UIView *b = [[UIView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 50, 50)];
UITapGestureRecognizer *bb =
[[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(handleDeviceClick:)];
[b addGestureRecognizer:bb];
[self.view addSubview:b];
```

And function:

```
-(void)handleDeviceClick:(UITapGestureRecognizer*)recognizer{
    NSLog(@"device click occured");
}
```

`UIGestureRecognizerDelegate` is added to my header file

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
// second view is called
// handleDeviceClick1: action of second view
// handleDeviceClick0: action of first view

-(void)handleDeviceClick1:(UITapGestureRecognizer*)recognizer{
   // call first view 
   [self handleDeviceClick0:recognizer] 
}
```

Comment: My real problem is that I have multiple views, not just 2, and number is not static number so I can create known number of tap gesture functions. I have to create only one function and call it multiple times for all subviews that have frame collided with clicked view.

Comment: You want: the last view is clicked, remaining views are below last view is set some properties? I think, you create NSArray contains all views need to set property. When last view is tap, you foreach all view and set properties. Is it OK?

Comment: I have multiple rectangles created in ViewController. When I click on rectangle that have rectangle behind it, I want only those two to change some property values. Not all rectangles in view controller. All views are stored in mutable array.

Comment: I think it can do with NSArray or NSDictionary. Ex: last view has tag is 10(array.count). The view is behind last view is 9(array.count-1).:)

Answer (score 0):

Then why don't you use

```
- (void)touchesBegan:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event{
    UITouch *touch = touches.anyObject;
    CGPoint point = [touch locationInView:self.view];
```

you just need to check if the clicked point is inside of each of your `subViews`

---

You don't have to create two `UITapGestures`, one is enough if you want them to use only one method.

Did you also add the `UIGestureRecognizerDelegate` to you header file?

```
@interface ViewController <UIGestureRecognizerDelegate>
```

Comment: I did add delegate to header file. Method is triggered, but only for view B, not for A that is added first.

Answer (score 0):

You should set `cancelsTouchesInView` to `NO` for your gesture recognisers, otherwise, the first recogniser to detect the touches will prevent the second one from doing it:

```
aa.cancelsTouchesInView = NO;
bb.cancelsTouchesInView = NO;
```

(actually, you only need doing this for the gesture recogniser associated to the top subview, but in case your view hierarchy might change, you are better off doing it on both).

Read it in the [docs](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UIGestureRecognizer_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instp/UIGestureRecognizer/cancelsTouchesInView):

> cancelsTouchesInView
>
> A Boolean value affecting whether touches are delivered to a view when a gesture is recognized.
>
> @property(nonatomic) BOOL cancelsTouchesInView
>
> Discussion
>
> When this property is YES (the default) and the receiver recognizes its gesture, the touches of that gesture that are pending are not delivered to the view and previously delivered touches are cancelled through a touchesCancelled:withEvent: message sent to the view. If a gesture recognizer doesn’t recognize its gesture or if the value of this property is NO, the view receives all touches in the multi-touch sequence.